Generics in custom component - unable to access enum-specific property
I'm creating a custom component: a list of cards.
Intended appearance:

This component accepts an array of generic type [T] and creates a card for each item in the array.
In this instance, I'm passing it an array of [PlantStage], which is an enum that represents various stages of gardening. Each stage has its own definition.
enum PlantStage: String, CaseIterable {
    case seed = "Seed"
    case germination = "Germination"
    case seedling = "Seedling"
    case bulb = "Bulb"
    case leafyGrowth = "Leafy Growth"
    case flowering = "Flowering"
    case pollination = "Pollination"
    case fruitFormation = "Fruit Formation"
    case vegetableFormation = "Vegetable Formation"
    case harvested = "Harvested"
    
    var definition: String {
        switch self {
        case .seed: "A small object from which a new plant can grow."
        case .germination: "The emergence of a tiny root and shoot."
        case .seedling: "A young plant with its first set of leaves."
        case .bulb: "An underground bulb from which a new plant can grow."
        case .leafyGrowth: "The growth of leaves, stems, and roots establishing the plant."
        case .flowering: "A stage where the plant produces flowers."
        case .pollination: "A period of pollen transfer leading to plant fertilization."
        case .fruitFormation: "The development of edible fruits."
        case .vegetableFormation: "The development of edible greens."
        case .harvested: "The act of gathering mature plants."
        }
    }
}

The problem is I can't access definition. The cards end up looking like this:

My component code:
struct CardSelectionList<T>: View where T: RawRepresentable, T.RawValue == String {
    
    let items: [T]

    let newlySelectedPillText: String
    let currentlyActivePillText: String
    
    @Binding var selectedItem: T
    @Binding var selectedIndex: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(0..<items.count, id: \.self) { i in
                    CardSelectable(
                        title: items[i].rawValue,
                        description: items[i].definition ?? nil,
                        currentlyActivePillText: currentlyActivePillText,
                        isNewlySelected: i == selectedIndex,
                        newlySelectedPillText: newlySelectedPillText
                    )
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selectedIndex = i
                        selectedItem = items[i]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    CardSelectionList(
        items: PlantStage.allCases,
        newlySelectedPillText: "New Stage",
        currentlyActivePillText: "Current Stage",
        selectedItem: .constant(.seed),
        selectedIndex: .constant(0)
    )
}

import SwiftUI

struct CardSelectable: View {
    
    let title: String
    let description: String?
    
//  let isCurrentlyActive: Bool
    let currentlyActivePillText: String
    
    let isNewlySelected: Bool
    let newlySelectedPillText: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
            HStack(spacing: 8) {
                Text(title)
                    .font(.handjet(.bold, size: 24))
//                  .opacity(isCurrentlyActive ? 0.5 : 1.0)
                
//              if isCurrentlyActive {
//                  TextPill(label: currentlyActivePillText, backgroundColor: Color.theme.backgroundLight)
//              }
                
                if isNewlySelected {
                    TextPill(label: newlySelectedPillText, backgroundColor: Color.theme.accentYellow)
                }
            }
            
            if let description = description {
                Text(description)
                    .font(.handjet(.medium, size: 20))
//                  .opacity(isCurrentlyActive ? 0.5 : 1.0)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .background(Color.theme.backgroundAccent)
        .overlay(isNewlySelected ? selectedBorder : nil)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}

I'm guessing because this component accepts an array of any type, not all types will have an associated definition. I tried addressing this by making card descriptions optional, but in this case it should have one.
I don't understand why items[i].definition doesn't return the definition when items[i] is of type PlantStage and all plant stages have an associated definition.

Don't use indexes with ForEach. ForEach is a view, not a for loop. Uses indexes in SwiftUI is a code smell and will cause you problems. You should use ForEach(items id:\.self) { item in, however the problem is probably in CardSelectable, which you haven't shown.

When asking a question, it is always helpful if you can provide code for a minimum, reproducible example, that is something that can be pasted into Xcode to demonstrate the problem.  Your code includes quite a few references to things that aren't provided or don't matter - Fonts, colour themes and views.

Using indices with ForEach is an anti-pattern in SwiftUI - ForEach is a view, not a for loop.
I have simplified your code in order to create a simplified example that I can build.
I have also modified it to use ForEach on items directly instead of using indices.
I created a protocol Defined which requires a definition property.
This works as expected.  Perhaps you can take this and use it as the basis for your own code, adding in the extra functionality you require.
protocol Defined {
    var definition: String { get }
}

enum PlantStage: String, CaseIterable, Defined {
    case seed = "Seed"
    case germination = "Germination"
    case seedling = "Seedling"
    case bulb = "Bulb"
    case leafyGrowth = "Leafy Growth"
    case flowering = "Flowering"
    case pollination = "Pollination"
    case fruitFormation = "Fruit Formation"
    case vegetableFormation = "Vegetable Formation"
    case harvested = "Harvested"
    
    var definition: String {
        switch self {
        case .seed: "A small object from which a new plant can grow."
        case .germination: "The emergence of a tiny root and shoot."
        case .seedling: "A young plant with its first set of leaves."
        case .bulb: "An underground bulb from which a new plant can grow."
        case .leafyGrowth: "The growth of leaves, stems, and roots establishing the plant."
        case .flowering: "A stage where the plant produces flowers."
        case .pollination: "A period of pollen transfer leading to plant fertilization."
        case .fruitFormation: "The development of edible fruits."
        case .vegetableFormation: "The development of edible greens."
        case .harvested: "The act of gathering mature plants."
        }
    }
}

struct CardSelectionList<T>: View where T: RawRepresentable, T.RawValue == String, T: Defined, T:Hashable {
    let items: [T]
    
    @State var selectedItem: T? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(items, id:\.self) { item in
                    CardSelectable(
                        title: item.rawValue,
                        description: item.definition, 
                        isSelected: self.selectedItem != nil && item == self.selectedItem!
                    )
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selectedItem = item
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    CardSelectionList(
        items: PlantStage.allCases
    )
}


struct CardSelectable: View {
    
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let isSelected: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
            HStack(spacing: 8) {
                Text(title).font(.title)
            }
            
            Text(description)
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
        .border(isSelected ? .black : .clear)
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}

